# How to add items dynamically to a custom adapter for ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I made adapter for ListView. If I fill the elements array before creating the adapter and linking it to the listView, the elements are displayed.
But if I use the updateItems () method to add items when the button is clicked, nothing happens.
Code of adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Lf> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int layout;
private List<Lf> lfs;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Lf> lfs) {
    super(context, resource, lfs);
    this.lfs = lfs;
    this.layout = resource;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Lf lf = lfs.get(position);

    viewHolder.name.setText(lf.getLf());
    viewHolder.freq.setText((int)lf.getFreq() + "");

    return convertView;
}

public void updateItems(List<Lf> lfs) {
    this.lfs.clear();
    this.lfs.addAll(lfs);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    final TextView name, freq;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_item_1);
        freq = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_item_2);
    }
}
}
```

Code of MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText1;
    ListView listView;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    List<Lf> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_list);
        // Working... Elements print on screen
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Lf temp = new Lf();
            temp.setLf("mean");
            temp.setFreq(100);
            elements.add(temp);
        }

        adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, elements);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    public void activity_button(View view) {
        adapter.updateItems(elements);
    }
}
```

If I click on the button, the existing items on the screen are cleared instead of a new one added. But in debug I see that elements normally passed to ListAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your adapter's `lfs`'s field and your activity's `elements` field both refer to the same `List` instance. This happens because you pass `elements` to the `ListAdapter` constructor, and then simply assign `this.lfs = lfs`.

So let's look at what happens when you pass `elements` to `updateItems()`...

```
public void updateItems(List<Lf> lfs) {
    this.lfs.clear(); // this.lfs and the input lfs are the same list, so this clears both
    this.lfs.addAll(lfs); // input lfs is now empty, so addAll() does nothing
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Probably the best thing to do is to create a copy of the list in your adapter's constructor.

```
this.lfs = new ArrayList<>(lfs);
```

Now your adapter and activity will reference different lists, so `this.lfs.clear()` won't accidentally clear out the very list you're passing to it.